# React, firebase, AuthContext questions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

I'm uncertain on how to define the AuthContext property here using the 'React.createContext()'.
In my signup.tsx file I keep getting:

TS2339: Property 'signup' does not exist on type '{}'.
TS2339: Property 'currentUser' does not exist on type '{}'.

So I'm assuming that 'React.createContext()' needs to have some sort of type passed in, but I'm not quite understanding how to accomplish this?

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'

const AuthContext = React.createContext({});

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }: any) {

    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<firebase.default.User>();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    function signup(email: string, password: string) {
        return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user: any) => {
            setCurrentUser(user);
            setLoading(false);
        });

    }, []);

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        signup
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={ value }>
            { !loading && children }
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Keep trying to add types and variables, but I'm not finding it.